# UINavigationController in Container View: push segue on table view cell does nothing

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have a container view which embeds a navigation controller (UINavigationController) with a root view that is a UITableViewController. One of the prototype cell has a push segue on selection to another UITableViewController. This is all via the storyboard in XCode 5. No actual code.

Unfortunately nothing happens when the cell is selected.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Check if the push segue is actually from the cell, sometimes we actually control + drag from the UITableViewController.

Comment: YEs the segue shows as part of the triggered segues when I select the cell.

Comment: Actually something happens but it's minor. The navigation bar gets updated with the back button but the view for the controller that is pushed doesn't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. In my controller showing that custom animated controller, I needed to use addChildViewController.

Answer (score 1):

I tried before with that structure and it should work well. Here is an example screenshot of the full storyboard:

[image]

Comment: That's what I have except that my container is not part of the initial controller but rather in a custom view that shows modally via a custom animation (Vs a modal segue.)

Comment: Does the segue only works with static table views? Mine is dynamic and it's the prototype cell that has the segue.

Comment: I also tried using a dynamic table view and it's still working. Have you tried to call the segue inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath delegate method? Have you checked if the navigationController of the Root table view is not nil?